# my java program is not working after I execute file io

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Hello so i have an assignment and my code is not working. I ask a user to input a filename and after that it freezes and does not process the number of lines. im doing something wrong but im not sure what? can someone please help me im really desperate this part is crashing my whole program and i might fail and i dont know who to ask :( for help

```
    public static void fileReader()
{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

  int catNum; 
  int dogNum; 
  int fishNum; 
  String fileName;

  System.out.println("Please enter the Name of the file you want to read in 
  from"); 
  fileName = sc.nextLine(); 
  System.out.println("this is the file name --> "+fileName);

  catNum = TestFile.getNum(fileName, "cat"); 
  dogNum = TestFile.getNum(fileName, "dog"); 
  fishNum = TestFile.getNum(fileName, "fish"); 

  System.out.println("THE CAT IS" +catNum); 
  System.out.println("THE DOG IS" +dogNum); 
  System.out.println("THE FISH IS" +fishNum);

}
```

i dont see anything wrong after i ask for the file name it freezes

> ```
> public static int getNum (String fileName, String word) {
> Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
> int lineNum = 0;
>
>
> FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
> InputStreamReader rdr; 
> BufferedReader bufRdr;
> String line;
>
> try {
>
>      fileStrm = new FileInputStream (fileName);
>      rdr = new InputStreamReader (fileStrm);
>      bufRdr = new BufferedReader (rdr);
>      line = bufRdr.readLine();
>
>      while (line != null)
>
>      {     
>         String firstWord = processString(line);
>
>         if(firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) //this submodule i going to get the number to create each array like e.g. how many states so that it can create it in country object 
>         {
>            lineNum++;   
>            line = bufRdr.readLine() ;
>         }
>      }
>
>      fileStrm.close();
> } 
> catch (IOException e)
> {
>   if (fileStrm != null)
>   {
>       try
>          {
>            fileStrm.close(); 
>          }
>       catch(IOException ex2)
>          {
>          System.out.println("This is Error");    
>          }
>   }
>   System.out.println("error reading file !!" +e.getMessage());
> }   
> return lineNum; }
> ```

the file looks something like this (each line is like this): 
CAT:NAME=doopie:SHORTNAME=doop:LANGUAGE=English:AREA=America:POPULATION=2222:POPREF=Census2016

Comment: This question is too broad, where exactly does the error occure? Try debugging and specifying the error.

Comment: the error occurs directly after i ask for the filename it freezes i added the extra code just to help bring some context @ArthurWietzorek

Answer (score 2):

Look at this while loop:

```
 while (line != null)
 {     
    String firstWord = processString(line);

    if(firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) //this submodule i going to get the number to create each array like e.g. how many states so that it can create it in country object 
    {
       lineNum++;   
       line = bufRdr.readLine() ;
    }
 }
```

If `firstWord.equalsIgnoreCase(word)` returns false, then what will happen? The value of `line` will never be updated and the loop will never exit.